# NodeJs Copy File Operation Not permitted Error

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I trying to copy img files from one directory into another directory. I am getting the following error `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile`. I have seen other posts regarding this error and tried their methods but none seem to be helpful.

```
      fs.exists(__dirname + `/img/${imgSrc}`, (exists)=>{
          if(exists){
            let imgPath = __dirname + `/img/${imgSrc}`
            let destinationFolder = __dirname + `/projects/${circuitName}-${fuseName}/${poleNumber}`



            fs.copyFile(imgPath, destinationFolder,(err)=>{
              if(err){
                console.log('Error. Unable to transfer file.', err)
              }else{
                console.log(`Success - File copied: ${imgSrc}`)
              }
            } )
          }else{
            console.log('file does not exist')
          }
        })
```

```
***folder structure***
server folder
 - img folder //where I am copying img file from
 - project folder//where I want to transfer into
 - package.json file 
 - main server.js file //where I am coding from
```

Comment: It's a permission issue. Make sure node has access to the directory. Where is the root dir of this? Is it under `/var/www` ?

Comment: Please see updated post. I added the folder structure

Comment: As @Andy says, it's permissions on the folder.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod -R 775 </img/folder and project/folder>`

Comment: I tried that and it says the syntax of the command is invalid

Comment: @Andy, so what i am thinking is that, since I am running code to create folders and save the imgs in there all in one execution is what is causing the problem. How can I give those newly created folders permission?

Comment: Found the solution. I needed to add the imgSrc also next to the destination path when running. For example: copyFile(imgPath, desitinationpath + imgSrc, ((error)=>{})

Answer (score 0):

Here, neither you're checking the `read` permission of your source file nor the `write` permission of the `destination` directory.

And by the way `fs.exists` is marked deprecated in the docs.

I've implemented a `copyFile` function below. See if it works for you.

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Note I'm using the promised version of fs
const fsp = fs.promises;

async function copyFile(sourceDirPath, destDirPath, filename) {
  const sourceFilePath = path.join(sourceDirPath, filename);
  const destFilePath = path.join(destDirPath, filename);
  try {
    await fsp.access(sourceFilePath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    await fsp.access(destDirPath, fs.constants.W_OK);
    await fsp.copyFile(sourceFilePath, destFilePath);

    console.log("File copied successfully.");
  } catch (ex) {
    if (ex.errno === -2)
      console.error(`File "${sourceFilePath}" doesn't exist.`);
    else if (ex.errno === -13)
      console.error(`Could not access "${path.resolve(destDirPath)}"`);
    else
      console.error(`Could not copy "${sourceFilePath}" to "${destDirPath}"`);

    // console.log(ex);
  }
}

copyFile("./", "./output", "file.txt");
```

My Folder structure:

```
|- copyFile.js
|- file.txt
|- output/
   |-
```

Comment: I did this but did not work. I do not have permission to it says

Comment: Then you don't have permission. That's simple :)

Comment: Found the solution. I needed to add the imgSrc also next to the destination path when running. For example:  copyFile(imgPath, desitinationpath + imgSrc, ((error)=>{})

Comment: Glad the problem is solved :)